# best way for design and print barcode label from handheld (ce5/compact framework) to zebra mobile printer

Tags: printing, compact-framework, barcode

**What i want is**
Design a label layout(barcode on it).
Scan the information by handheld and print the label directly from mobile printer linked with bluetooth.
**want to know**:
best way to implement this? see my preferences list below
1) free of charge
2) the API should have 2D barcode support
3) label layout can be designed by Drag-and-drop. The best is a visual studio control. so we do not need too much coding.
Hope someone has experience can share some to me, what cotrol? what liberary? Must use zebra specific printing language?
Kindly show a technique chain of the best(easy, free). Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and go with the Zebra SDK (for windows ce too). I assume there is no drag and drop GUI designer tool. But you may examine the code generated by a label designer application printing to a zebra printer using file: as output port.

Zebra provides good SDKs, samples and support. For example to print a QR code:

^XA^FO100,100^BQN,2,10^FDYourTextHere^FS^XZ

You see, it is more or less readable where to replace text to get another QR barcode.

see also https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&channel=SAMPLE_CODE

You may need to study the ZPL programmers guide and then you can start to print your own mind-designed labels. Printing meeans to send ZPL code lines directly to the printer.